# Convert string to PowerShell DateTime

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have the following string: `"02-06-2018 16:25:28"`. I need to convert it to a `DateTime` object. I tried doing this:

```bsh
[DateTime]::ParseExact('02-06-2018 16:25:28', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss', $null)
```

But it did not work:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Is there another function other than `[DateTime]::ParseExact` that supports parsing the string in this fomat `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss`?

I'm using PowerShell v5.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [`HH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for a 24-hour clock. `hh` is for a 12-hour clock, which doesn't recognize a 16th hour. I would also recommend using `InvariantCulture` instead of `$null`, as the latter sometimes won't work.

```bsh
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
[DateTime]::ParseExact('02-06-2018 16:25:28', 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss', $culture)
```

Comment: Ah, that was it. Thanks a lot. (btw, edit your answer, you wrote 'hh', not 'HH' in the code.

Comment: @RonaDona Yeah, thanks for the heads up. BTW, your example timestamp looks like it was from today. If that's the case you also need to change `dd-MM-yyyy` to `MM-dd-yyyy`.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass date/time strings to `Get-Date` as well, it will convert them for you: `get-date "02-06-2018 16:25:28"` for example.  This will return a System.DateTime object and can be manipulated in the usual ways by powershell.